# How can I hide a line behind marker?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw a graph for my school report.

As I should use a marker that has a small dot at center of it, I can't use the default filled circle marker.
So I referred to the [STIX font table](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf) and found that [U+2299](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEe6R.png) satisfies the requirement. However, when I executed the code below, I got a [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Mlx.png) in which the line penetrates the plot. How can I hide the line behind these markers so that it won't overlap with them? Any advice would be much appreciated.

```py
values = [i for i in range(3)]
plt.plot(values, values, label="line")
plt.scatter(values, values, marker=u"$\u2299$", s=500, label="marker")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: you could plot the data twice. first with a white circle and then above a second time with the desired character.

Comment: Altenative to `marker=u"$\u2299$"` is to use `marker=r'$\odot$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you are looking for something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
values = [i for i in range(3)]
plt.plot(values, values, label="line", zorder=1)
plt.scatter(values, values, s=250, c='w', zorder=2)
plt.scatter(values, values, marker=u"$\u2299$", s=500, label="marker", zorder=3)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I desired! Thank you